# Ajax with Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to use few of the ajax control toolkit in asp.net mvc
say, Validator CallOut,ModalPopUp.

and even i need to put a gridview in an update panel?
can anybody give any valuable link so that i can look into it?

Comment: Nimesh - I agree with Morph. The AJAX Control Toolkit is incompatible with ASP.NET MVC. If you want to incorporate AJAX techniques into your website, then you should consider methodologies that are more native to ASP.NET MVC. SO can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=asp.net-mvc%2bajax&sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: +1 for bringing this topic to life, one of the reasons to pursue ASP.NET MVC is to take control of what is being rendered to the end user rather than relying on bulky controls that muddy the gap between presentation and actions / business logic.

Comment: @Mayo: I would downvote your comment if I could. Nimesh is trying to reconcile two incompatible technologies.

Comment: @Jim: Why negative?  I didn't state that they weren't incompatible, rather that they are incompatible by design.

Comment: @Mayo: Right. OK. Well if one newbie's question can provide clarity for other newbies, then maybe the question deserves +1.

Comment: from the nikihls blog,
http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx
i could see he is using the waterbox textmark, i dont know how he doing that... so after seeign that i thought y can't i use ajax controls like, modalpopup,validator call out etc..
thats the reason y i started investigating on this....

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have AJAX functionality with ASP.NET MVC I suggest you do that with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (the Javascript framework officially supported by Microsoft and shipping with VS 2010). UpdatePanel was supported in ASP.NET, it is not in ASP.NET MVC.

See a tutorial on how to build some AJAX functionality with ASP.NET MVC [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-Net.aspx) and [here](http://spellcoder.com/blogs/beckham/archive/2008/03/14/9807.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd want to put an update panel and a gridview in an asp.net mvc application.

I don't know what you're trying to do, or why you picked asp.net mvc, but it sounds like you just need to stick to asp.net if you want to do those kind of things. MVC works very differently than classic webforms.

Comment: regarding the gridview, i have a similiar requirement where in i need to display contents with edit, delete and re-order buttons.
i dont know whether the Gridview with MVC is possible or not, i am just trying all those, and if it wokr then its great..
could you please tell me what will i use instead of GridView in MVC

Comment: Something like jqGrid for example. You'll have to go through a bit of a learning curve, but it's very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Also keep in mind that the AJAX framework that Microsoft bolted on to ASP.Net webforms requires a full viewstate postback, so that kills one of the benefits of the MVC framework, which is to not require viewstate for control persistence.

Comment: so u mean to say that its not possible to add the ajax controls into the asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net MVC has no concept of controls, the standard Web Form controls do not work with MVC.

Why are you trying to integrate WebForm controls in MVC?

Comment: from NIkhil's Blog, i could see the integration with the ajax. he is demonstrating the waterboxtextmark.
http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx
thats the reason why i thought of integrating the ajax controls.
in his sample code he is using system.web.extension 3.6.0.0
but i am not able to add any reference as such. do i need to install  anything else to get this 3.6.0.0 version???

Answer (score 0):

There is no `controls` for `ASP.NET MVC`. BUT, there is an `extensions`, you can look to `DevExpress`, here is a link:

http://mvc.devexpress.com/